# Licensing C++ wrapper of C shared lib

Tags: license-file, zlib

I'm doing a little C++ wrapper around a C lib that uses the **[zlib](https://www.zlib.net/zlib_license.html)** license.

I suppose I have to include this license in my wrapper's files.

1. But what about the other files? I was planning on making a shared library.
2. Overall, what license should my shared library be released on?